# PHP mail() function and scalability

Tags: php, email, scalability

suppose my site grows such that I will need to send out hundreds and thousands of emails per day....will the PHP mail() function still suffice as a solution to such scenario or will I have to implement an alternative solution? If so, what solution should I seek in such scenario?

Comment: its a matter of performance but i think its same to use mail function or socket connection i mean SMTP direct connection for sure .

Comment: Forget that you ever heard about PHP's mail() function. It's the equivalent of a screwdriver you buy at a dollar store. It'll work once or twice, and then fail spectacularly and horribly. Use a real mail package such as PHPMailer or Swiftmailer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail()` opens and closes a socket each time it sends a message so no, it's not the best idea as those operations are quite inefficient.

A better solution is to use PHP's [PEAR Mail extension](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected); this was designed for sending emails *en masse*.

As an extension to PEAR Mail, there's also [Mail_queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/) which puts messages into a queue and sends them in the background. This might be a better option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of thousands will not be easy. Technically it is possible and there should be nothing to stop you, but do not expect it to be an easy task.

A site that 'has to' send that amount, will have to take in consideration DKIM signing which is a time-consuming process.

Let's for example say that an email will need 0.5 a second to be signed, queued and processed.. that's just an example:

100,000 Emails
= 50,000 Seconds
= 13.5 Hours

To do the trick, you will have to consider buying an X number of VPS servers (in multiple Geo locations preferably) and define each as a mail relay.. Then use a queue system to send your mails using all those gateways.

The same 100K emails above will be sent in 2 hours assuming you have 6 mail relay servers.

Hope this clears some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It will work but it will be very slow (like take hours). You should definitely look into some commercial packages meant for handling this sort of thing.

Check out - http://sendgrid.com/

It's easy to setup, pretty inexpensive, and they guarantee that your mail gets to your clients!

Comment: Advertising? 
If not, please add a small disclaimer in the answer's footer so that people know you're not an affiliate trying to make pennies here ;) People are afraid of clicking you know ;)

Comment: no not advertising... have just used it before for something similar to what the poster wants.

Disclaimer: I don't work for, or care about sendgrid.com I just think it's a good service.